# How do I make "pretty name" within sheet.appendRow?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code works, however, I want to have a pretty name showing for the sheets' url, like `link` rather than displaying the `url`.  I know how to do that with `=hyperlink`, but here, I am at a loss:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.appendRow(["Link", "Name", "Type", "ID"]);
  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    file = contents[i];
    var value1,value2,value3;
    if (file.getFileType()==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {
      var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      value1 = otherSheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
      value2 = otherSheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
      value3 = otherSheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
    } else {
      value1 = null; value2 = null; value3 = null; value4 = null;
    }
    sheet.appendRow([ file.getUrl(),value1,value2,value3,value4]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I added:

```
var name = "link"; 
var semi = ";";
var hyp = "=hyperlink(\""; var quot = "\""; var clos = ")";
var pp = hyp + url + quot + semi + quot + name + quot + clos;
```

Then changed it to `sheet.appendRow)[link, value1...`